# TLS 1.2 Cipher in Suite JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, tls1.2

I am trying to connect to a MS SQL server from a Tomcat server over TLS 1.2. How can I know the cipher suite used for HANDSHAKING between MS SQL and a jdbc driver?

Comment: You could use debug logging, see [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: i tried the same . There are so  many "ClientHello" . How can i be sure which one is right?